# Insert() user function equivalent in postgreSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

Is there any equivalent function in postgresql to the insert() user function in mysql?

Some relevant docs on the subject: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-insert-function.php

Thank you.

Comment: Look at the [`overlay` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html). Using the example from the link you provided: `select overlay('Originalstring' placing ' insert ' from 4 for 5);` and result is `Ori insert string`

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, man. Thank you very much.